# How to get 2 wireless xbox360 controllers to work at the same time?

Tags: linux-mint, steam

I have two wireless Xbox360 controllers  that I would like to get to work simultaneously in Linux Mint 17.2. Xboxdrv is installed and a single controller work wonders with Steam games, however, the wireless receiver can only map one.

Can't simply make a new device file called: "*/dev/input/js1*" next to "*/dev/input/js0*", or can I?  How do I assign the other one to the userspace?

Comment: Perhaps related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/580721/xbox-360-controller-keeps-blinking