# Xbox 360 controller keeps blinking

Tags: linux-mint, kernel-modules, games

I'm trying to use my xbox 360 wireless controllers with linux mint.

I was able to get all controllers (4) to link (using xboxdrv), but it was as if the right trigger was held down for all controllers, all the time.

I then uninstalled xboxdrv, then only one controller would connect and the others keep blinking.

What can I do to get all controllers to connect?

Answer (score 0):

Run the command

```
sudo modprobe xpad
```